# JavaScript: More than just a countdown/countup script

Tags: javascript

I seriously hope someone here can help me with this one... eventhough it's somewhat complicated to explain what I'm searching for.

Basically I'm looking for a "countdown/countup" javascript - *sounding pretty straight forward, right?*

I have found lots of variations of this sort of script but none of them meets the following requirements.

What I specifically need, is a script which on page load starts counting down from 36000 sec. and when reaching 0 sec. immediately starts counting back up to 36000 sec.

Meanwhile, I have these two div's which ought to both effect and be effected by the script:

```
<style>
.indicator {
width: 20px;
height: 8px;
}
</style>

<div class="percent">100%</div>
<div class="indicator"></div>
```

As you can see, the innerHTML of the first div starts out being 100% and should be reduced by 1 when the script has counted past every 360th sec.
*(e.g.: when counted past the 3600th sec. the innerHTML should be 90%)*

The second div has a width of 20px which should be reduced by 1px when the script has counted past every 1800th sec.
*(e.g.: when counted past the 3600th sec. the width should be 18px)*

- 36000 sec. = 100% = 20px
- 18000 sec. = 50% = 10px
- 3600 sec. = 10% = 2px
- 1800 sec. = 5% = 1px
- 360 sec. = 1% = 0px

As mentioned before, the script should start counting back upwards when it has reached 0 sec.
When this happens, the className of the second div should change from **indicator** to **charging** and the innerHTML of the first div should increase appropriately according to the sec's counted past.
*(exactly as when the script was counting downwards)*

However, when the countup reaches the 36000th sec. it isn't supposed to just start counting back down again, but rather pause there and change the className of the second div from **charging** to **charged**.
Needless to say, the innerHTML of the first div should at this point be 100%.
From here on, the script is only to commence countdown if the second div is clicked, in which case the className of the second div should change from **charged** back to **indicator**.

Furthermore, the countdown/countup is to be reversed whenever the second div is clicked, simultaniously changing of its className.

- **Countdown**: `<div class="indicator"></div>`
- **Countup**: `<div class="charging"></div>`

I apologize for the long explanation and my poor english grammar...

Hope somebody is able to make sence of this :)

Comment: The explanation is clear. But you should write what you've tried, otherwise it sounds like, please write my code for me! SO is about "Here's what I'm doing, why isn't it working?"

Comment: check out http://jsfiddle.net/, great way to demo what you've tried and for us to tinker with it to make it work.

Comment: Your problem looked like fun so I started a fiddle.  I am out of time to work on stuff but maybe you would like to see what I had so far. http://jsfiddle.net/tNrfA/20/

Comment: Looking great! I does the countdown/countup perfectly :)

Comment: Should you get some more time on your hands to fiddle width the rest (like; instant reversal of count direction onclick, className change onclick and className change at end of countdown or countup) i'd be very interested in seeing what you come up with :)

Comment: Hey @robbieAreBest I tried fiddling with your script and managed to get the three classes shown :) http://jsfiddle.net/LDpb9/2/ But don't really know how to implement the formentioned functions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like a timer that is called every 10 seconds (since your points of change mod 10 = 0), and check to see if a variable is at one of those values. For example something like:

```
var totalTime = 36000;
var timeLeft = totalTime;

setInterval(countdown, 10000);

function countdown()
{
    timeLeft -= 10;

    //Change innerhtml to timeLeft/totalTime * 100 + "%";
}
```

That should get you started at least I think. You would probably use setTimeout instead though so you could eventually end the decrementation, and start incrementing.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code.. It seems to be working but it uses 100 seconds and for some reason the ID clicking isn't working anymore.  You should be able to figure it out to work for your specific seconds setup.  Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6anju/7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    count_down(); //<-- When the page loads

    $('.indicator').click(function() {
        /** This works.. Just make sure you change the ID's properly **/
    });

    //*  Not working correctly. jQuery version type correct? *//
    $('#charging').click(function() {
        // Change ID back:
        var change_id = document.getElementById('charging');
        change_id.id = "indicator";
        count_down();
    });

    $('#charged').click(function() {
        // Change ID back:
        var change_id = document.getElementById('charged');
        change_id.id = "indicator";
        count_down();
    });

});

function count_down() {

    var counter = 100000; // 100 seconds
    var change_width_every = 5; // Change every 5 seconds
    var current_width = 20;  // Current width in px
    var current_percent = 100; // Current percent

    // Count down and run every 1 second
    var count_down = setInterval(function() {

        counter = counter - 1000; // Take a second away
        current_percent--; // Take away 1 percent
        change_width_every--;  // Take away 1 from the 5 seconds befor width change
        document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = current_percent + "%"; // Edit the percent div

        if (change_width_every <= 0) { // If we exhaust our 5
            current_width--; // Edit your current width integer
            document.getElementById('indicator').style.width = current_width + "px"; // update the battery
            change_width_every = 5; // reinitialize
        }

        if (counter <= 0) {
            clearInterval(count_down); // kill the counter
            count_up(); // start counting up
        }

    }, 1000);
}

function count_up() {

    var counter = 0;
    var change_width_every = 5
    var current_width = 0;
    var current_percent = 0;
    // change the id to charging:
    var change_id = document.getElementById('indicator');
    change_id.id = 'charging';

    var counting = setInterval(function() {

        counter = counter + 1000;
        current_percent++;
        change_width_every--;
        document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = current_percent + "%";

        if (change_width_every <= 0) {
            current_width++;
            document.getElementById('charging').style.width = current_width + "px";
            change_width_every = 5 // reinitialize
        }

        if (counter >= 100000) {
            change_id = document.getElementById('charging');
            change_id.id = "charged";
            clearInterval(counting);
        }

    }, 1000);

}
```

​

Comment: I've changed the class' to id's and just tried to run it, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. As in, no counting appears to be going on. Looking at your script it does however seem as if you've gotten the main functionality in there like; immediate countup when reaching 0 sec., stopping at 36000 sec., changing id at count end and changing id on click. Only thing missing is the ability to change counting direction instantaneously by an onclick event. I greatly appreciate your effort and hope that you'd perhaps care to skim through it again if you get a little more time on your hands. Thx

Comment: Hey @burmat I've started a fiddle with your script hoping you could help me get it to work :) http://jsfiddle.net/6anju/1/

Comment: @Ace: I am working on it right now.. I saw a couple errors right off the bat. When you say 36000, do you mean 36 seconds (which is 36000 in JavaScipt), or do you mean 36,000 seconds in real time.